# Add point at map centre in ggplot in r

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, dplyr, geosphere

I want to add point at every state centre.

I know `centroid()` from `geosphere` package can do this. It can only compute one longitude and latitude, but I have 49 states and I do not want to compute it one by one.

I also know `coordinates()` from `sp` package can do this. It needs the argument class input is `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` and `sp` but the `us` map I get from `map_data()` is a dataframe.

Any suggestion?

```
library(scatterpie)
library(tidyverse)
library(geosphere)
library(ggnewscale)
us <- map_data('state') %>% as_tibble()

n = length(unique(us$region))

# creat fake mapping data

temperature_data <- tibble(region = unique(us$region),
                           temp = rnorm(n = n))

coords <- us %>% select(long, lat, region) %>% distinct(region, .keep_all = T)


coords_data <- tibble(region = unique(us$region)) %>% left_join(coords)
                       


us <- left_join(us, temperature_data)

# add point
p + geom_map(map = us, aes(map_id = region, fill = temp), color = 'grey') +
    geom_point(data = category_data, aes(long, lat))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute the centroids by grouping the data by `region` and then modify for each group using `purrr::group_modify()`:

```r
centroids <- us %>% 
  group_by(region) %>% 
  group_modify(~ data.frame(centroid(cbind(.x$long, .x$lat))))
```

Then plot everything together:

```r
ggplot(us, aes(x = long, y = lat)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(group = group)) +
  geom_map(map = us, aes(map_id = region, fill = temp), color = 'grey') +
  geom_point(data = centroids, aes(lon, lat), col = "red")
```

[image]